# Deploy Scheduler Job in liferay 7 not work

Tags: java, liferay, quartz-scheduler

I created a plugin on ecplise with a portlet inside to create a scheduler. My class implements MessageListener and doing the Override of the method "public void receive (Message message) throws MessageListenerException" I can have a scheduler that is activated correctly. Now the problem is on the deployment. In a clean environment it takes place correctly and my job does its job; but if I try to do an undeploy and reload a new version I get the following message

> WARN [liferay / scheduler_engine-1] [QuartzSchedulerEngine: 804]
>   Scheduler job scheduler.Attivita.scheduler.Attivita already exists

and the scheduler does not start anymore.

"Activity" is the name of my class clearly.

Do you have any suggestions?

```
public class Attivita implements MessageListener {

private static Logger _logger;
public final static StringBuilder logFile = new StringBuilder();

@Override
public void receive(Message message) throws MessageListenerException {
    _logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

         _logger.info("Inizio Scheduler");

   }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are using liferay 6.2 old type way to create a scheduler... pls share some code..

Comment: I'm using liferay 7. The schedule works on a first deployment; if I update the version it gives me the message. It seems that the undeploy does not work.

Comment: Maybe you have to unregister the scheduler is a proper way.  Share some code..
In case I have some sample to provide you. Wait a while.

Comment: as Daniele already mentioned  yours seems to be the old way.. blade has samples .. https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/7.1/maven/extensions/scheduler-entry